# Excluding MFA for PowerBI admin to use in embedding the dashboard in my application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi-embedded, multi-factor-authentication

I am new to Azure. I have embedded the PowerBI dashboard in my application successfully.
Now , I am enabling MFA in my Azure account.My PowerBI admin needs to be excluded from the MFA to use that credential in the application.

Can anyone please suggest some method to do it?

Thanks and regards,
Bala

Comment: What kind of method did you use for embedding the PowerBI dashboard?

Comment: Don't use admin account for embedding.